# Update Spark Dataframe's window function row_number column for Delta Data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to update the dataframes's row number column for the delta data. I have implemented the base load's row number as below:

Input Data:

```
val base = List(List("001", "a", "abc"), List("001", "a", "123"),List("003", "c", "456") ,List("002", "b", "dfr"), List("003", "c", "ytr"))
  .map(row => (row(0), row(1), row(2)))

val DS1 = base.toDF("KEY1", "KEY2" ,"VAL")

DS1.show()

+----+----+---+
|KEY1|KEY2|VAL|
+----+----+---+
| 001|   a|abc|
| 001|   a|123|
| 003|   c|456|
| 002|   b|dfr|
| 003|   c|ytr|
+----+----+---+
```

Now I have added the row number using a window function as below :

```
val baseDF =  DS1.select(col("KEY1"), col("KEY2"), col("VAL") ,row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(col("KEY1"), col("KEY2")).orderBy(col("KEY1"), col("KEY2").asc)).alias("Row_Num"))
baseDF.show()

+----+----+---+-------+
|KEY1|KEY2|VAL|Row_Num|
+----+----+---+-------+
|001 |a   |abc|1      |
|001 |a   |123|2      |
|002 |b   |dfr|1      |
|003 |c   |456|1      |
|003 |c   |ytr|2      |
+----+----+---+-------+
```

Now the delta load comes a below :

```
val delta = List(List("001", "a", "y45") ,List("002", "b", "444"))
  .map(row => (row(0), row(1), row(2)))

val DS2 = delta.toDF("KEY1", "KEY2" ,"VAL")
DS2.show()

+----+----+---+
|KEY1|KEY2|VAL|
+----+----+---+
| 001|   a|y45|
| 002|   b|444|
+----+----+---+
```

So the expected updated result should be:

```
baseDF.show()

|KEY1|KEY2|VAL|Row_Num|
+----+----+---+-------+
|001 |a   |abc|1      |
|001 |a   |123|2      |
| 001|   a|y45|3      | -----> Delta record
|002 |b   |dfr|1      |
| 002|   b|444|2      | -----> Delta record 
|003 |c   |456|1      |
|003 |c   |ytr|2      |
+----+----+---+-------+
```

Any suggestions to implement this solution using dataframes/datasets?
Can we achieve the above solution with spark rdd's `zipWithIndex`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to add the delta with updated row numbers is to: 1) add column `Row_Num` with a large number in `DS2`, 2) union `baseDF` with it, and 3) calculate the new row numbers, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val combinedDF = baseDF.union(
  DS2.withColumn("Row_Num", lit(Long.MaxValue))
)

val resultDF = combinedDF.select(
  col("KEY1"), col("KEY2"), col("VAL"), row_number().over(
    Window.partitionBy(col("KEY1"), col("KEY2")).orderBy(col("Row_Num"))
  ).alias("New_Row_Num")
)

resultDF.show
+----+----+---+-----------+
|KEY1|KEY2|VAL|New_Row_Num|
+----+----+---+-----------+
| 003|   c|456|          1|
| 003|   c|ytr|          2|
| 002|   b|dfr|          1|
| 002|   b|444|          2|
| 001|   a|abc|          1|
| 001|   a|123|          2|
| 001|   a|y45|          3|
+----+----+---+-----------+
```

Comment: val resultDF = combinedDF.select(
  col("KEY1"), col("KEY2"), col("VAL"), row_number().over(
    Window.partitionBy(col("KEY1"), col("KEY2")).orderBy(col("Row_Num"))
  ).alias("New_Row_Num")
) .  how can i apply DESC for window partitionBy ??

Comment: @Jack, if I understand your question correctly, you can simply specify `orderBy(col("Row_Num").desc)`.